# Rails - better flow control - loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am grabbing value data: name, uid, highschool_name, graduateschool_name like this:

```
def add_friends
    facebook.get_connections("me", "friends", :fields => "name, id, education").each do |hash|
      self.friends.where(:name => hash['name'], 
                         :uid => hash['id'], 
                         :highschool_name => hash['education']['school']['name'] unless hash["education"].blank?,
                         :graduateschool_name => hash['education']['school']['name'] unless hash["education"].blank?).
                   first_or_create
    end
end
```

From an array of hash:

```
"education": [
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "110703012290674", 
        "name": "Kunskapsgymnasiet Malmö"
      }, 
      "year": {
        "id": "136328419721520", 
        "name": "2009"
      }, 
      "type": "High School"
    }, 
    {
      "school": {
        "id": "112812485399398", 
        "name": "Malmö University"
      }, 
      "year": {
        "id": "118118634930920", 
        "name": "2012"
      }, 
      "concentration": [
        {
          "id": "104076956295773", 
          "name": "Computer Science"
        }
      ], 
      "type": "Graduate School", 
      "classes": [
        {
          "id": "165093923542525", 
          "name": "Programmering", 
          "description": "Kursen fokuserar på metoder och tekniker vid utveckling av webbapplikationer med hjälp av HTML5."
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
```

EDIT:
This code dosent work. I would like to pick every hichschool and Graduate School from this array of hash and save it.

Comment: I've seen this hash before. :) Wasn't my previous answer useful to you? Are you asking something else?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev, I have but not in the same fashion. I have tried to implement the same tatice on this method but with out the any result.

Comment: This code doesn't work, right? Describe how exactly it does not work. And what you would like it to do.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I would like it to work like the last method but I get confused with this method structure, do you know what I mean? =)

Comment: No, I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I would to do the same thing like my last question but with this method

Answer (score 0):

```
high_schools = response['education'].collect{|ed| ed['school']['name'] if ed['type'] == "High School" } 
grad_schools = response['education'].collect{|ed| ed['school']['name'] if ed['type'] == "Graduate School" }
```

Comment: can you give a more indeep explation?

Comment: This method uses the built-in Array.collect method to gather all of the High School names into a single array; and then does the same for the Graduate School names.

Comment: Where in the method shall I put it?

Comment: After you retrieve your response from facebook.  The response in the above code is the education hash that you described.